# Best practice for unit testing gRPC

Tags: java, junit5, grpc-java

is this a best practice while performing integration tests on the gRPC services? i.e. opening and closing channels after each unit test using annotations @BeforeEach and @AfterEach

```
private ManagedChannel channel;

private DepartmentServiceGrpc.DepartmentServiceBlockingStub deptService;

@BeforeEach
public void initEach(){
    channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

    deptService = DeptServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
}

@AfterEach
public void cleanUpEach(){
    channel.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JUnit 4, you can use the `GrpcCleanupRule`. If you're using JUnit 5, you can use the OSS [grpc-test](https://github.com/asarkar/grpc-test) I created.

Comment: Could you provide me with full example on how to use that? I still can not understand the usage instruction in github.

Comment: This is interesting, but, how can I use it?

Comment: @Arefe What in the README is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC provides junit4 rule called [GrpcCleanupRule](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/testing/src/main/java/io/grpc/testing/GrpcCleanupRule.java). Note that it is junit4 rule.

Comment: I actually was using GrpcCleanupRule but then I ran into problems in a case when I've two services added on my server `.addService(new Service1()).addService(new Service2())` and I just couldn't figure out and went this route instead.

Comment: if you have a unexpected problem, considering filing an issue on grpc github. can you explain more about what doesn't work?